# Javascript array fills with empty items

Tags: javascript

I'm parsing a json file and at this point have gathered up data from a spreadsheet. Can anyone tell me why when I set an array like this

```
function getfaq()
        {
          fetch(faq, settings)
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then((json) => {
                for(var i = 5;i<json.feed.entry.length;i++)
                {
                  col = json.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.col
                  faqdata[i-5] = [];
                  if(col == 1) {
                    faqdata[i-5][0] = "Question:"
                    faqdata[i-5][1] = json.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.inputValue
                  } else if(col == 2)
                  {
                    faqdata[i-5][0] = "Answer:"
                    if(json.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.inputvalue != "")
                    {
                      faqdata[i-5][1] = json.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.inputValue
                    } else {
                      faqdata[i-5][1] = "N/A"
                    }
                  } else if(col == 3)
                  {
                    faqdata[i-5][0] = "Command:"
                    faqdata[i-5][1] = json.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.inputValue
                  } else if(col == 4)
                  {
                    faqdata[i-5][0] = "Image:"
                    faqdata[i-5][1] = json.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.inputValue
                  } else if(col == 5)
                  {
                    faqdata[i-5][0] = "Reference:"
                    faqdata[i-5][1] = json.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.inputValue
                  }
                }
                for(var j = 0;j<faqdata.length;j++)
                {
                  if(faqdata[j][0].includes("Command:"))
                  {
                    faqC[j] = faqdata[j][1]
                    console.log(faqdata[j][1]);
                  }
                }
                
              })
            }
```

my output looks like this

```
    [
  <1 empty item>,  'reset',
  <2 empty items>, 'justmaxed',
  <2 empty items>, 'ascended',
  <1 empty item>,  'masteries',
  <1 empty item>,  'gliding',
  <1 empty item>,  'mounts',
  <2 empty items>, 'livingworld',
  <2 empty items>, 'gold',
  <2 empty items>, 'dungeons',
  <3 empty items>, 'fractals',
  <1 empty item>,  'raid'
]
```

when I just throw a log into it my output looks like

```
reset
justmaxed
ascended
masteries
gliding
mounts
livingworld
gold
dungeons
fractals
raid
```

I don't understand why it's adding in  when I try to import it into an array but when I log the data it displays correctly.
I have tried my best to figure it out but I do not know why its adding into the array like this...

Comment: Can you add more details, please?

Comment: Please include the initial data for those arrays (Or a small sample if it's a large array)

Comment: Because some of the items in `faqdata` don't satisfy your condition. Yet, when they do, you're pushing to a specific index (`j`) that has incremented regardless. Try `faqC.push(faqdata[j][1])` instead

Comment: what happens if your IF condition isn't met?  The j counter still increments, so you might end up setting array[0]. skipping array[1] and [2], then adding array[3].

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to avoid setting nonconsecutive elements of the array by index is to instead use [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

instead of

```
faqC[j] = faqdata[j][1]
```

try

```
faqC.push(faqdata[j][1])
```

ALSO, in the spirit of modern functional programming, consider replacing the entire for loop with something like:

```
const faqC = faqdata.filter(fd => fd[0].includes("Command:")).map(fd => fd[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable j is being used as the index for faqC and causing your issue. If j is 3 but faqC currently contains only one item, index 2 of faqC will be left empty. To solve this issue use `faqC.push(faqdata[j][1)` so faqC is populated consecutively.